# NLOG real time logging

Tags: c#, nlog

How to configure NLOG to have real time in log file?
Real time I mean time when operation was executed (to be more precisely - when log method was called).

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}|${exception:format=toString}"
        fileName="D:/Logs/${shortdate}.log" />
```

{longdate} seems to be a writing to log file date/time.

Comment: Have you enabled Autoflush?

Comment: What makes you think `${longdate}` is not the "real time" ?

Comment: Maybe you can gain accuracy: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Time-Source if that's what this is.

Comment: **Autoflush** - according to the documentation has impact on performance: "automatically flush the file buffers after each log message".

Comment: @Irek Well yes, writing log messages as soon as they're not logged, and not buffering them, will slow things down. That's why it's not done by default.

Comment: @canton7 do you know any proper way to have real date/time in file ? Writing own appender ? I can't believe that standard implementation doesn't cover such option.

Comment: You set `Autoflush`, and suck up the performance penalty. You'll have to pay the same performance penalty if you write your own appender: that's an intrinsic property of how writing to files works

Comment: Why do you think you need "real time logging"? What's the underlying goal that you think doing that will accomplish?

Comment: @mason I need 'real time' measure to know when some actions finish and compare with other process log. Problem seems to be resolved when I use AccurateUTC as described in https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Time-Source

Comment: @Irek That doesn't mean you need real time. You need to understand that when an event gets logged, it immediately captures a timestamp. So even though it may be a little while before it makes it into a log file, the timestamp on it will still reflect when the event got logged from your code. So you don't need realtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the Logger, then it will create a LogEventInfo-object that captures a timestamp.

```
log.Info("Hello World");   // Captures timestamp
```

When using the NLog Layout `${longdate}` then it will output the original timestamp captured. Independent of how long it takes for the LogEventInfo to reach the final NLog target, then it will always print the captured timestamp.

Any issues you have with precision or delay is probably caused by the default time-source:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Time-Source

Any issues you have with performance of the NLog FileTarget can probably be fixed by using `KeepFileOpen=true` and `ConcurrentWrites=false`:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance